# Which one should I use: fell off/ have fallen

Tags: tense, american-english, present-perfect, past-simple

Situation:  I am sitting in my class and seeing that magnetic pin is falling off the board down on the floor! Now I’d like to describe what just happened!

> The magnetic pin have fallen from the board!

or

> The magnetic pin fell off the board!

Which one I need to use and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference.

Although "fell" is the past of "fall", and you will find the same definition of "fallen", "fell" is the action that leads to falling.
Example:

> Suddenly, he fell from the roof. As he was falling, he thought of his family.

In your example, I would say that "fell" describes the action of the magnetic pin falling from the board. If you actually witnessed that, then you could say "it fell". However, if you just saw the pin lying on the floor you would more likely say "it has fallen", which is a fair assumption.

Answer (score 2):

"The magnetic pin *has* fallen *off* the board!" or "The magnetic pin fell off the board!" Both of these are fine and both are just as good as the other.

Note that I have changed the word '*have*' to '*has*'. This is because the noun right before is singular (just one magnetic pin) but if it was plural (magnetic pins) then you could use '*have*'.

I also changed the word '*from*' to '*off*' because it just sounds a little more natural. You could also say '*from*' but it sounds a little too formal.